# Enable or disable gtk.Button in PyGTK

Tags: python, pygtk

How can I set a `gtk.Button` enabled or disabled in PyGTK?

Answer (score 34):

```
my_button.set_sensitive(False)
```

True is enabled, False disabled.  See the [gtk.Widget documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--set-sensitive).

Comment: Note, sensitivity can also be turned off for any widget, so you can desensitize an entire box, form, window, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to see the object then you could `button.set_visible(False)` to hide it or `button.set_visible(True)` to show it. This will prevent users from seeing the button.

Comment: Useful information if additional to first answering the question.